# I want to make a woocommerce subscription product which subscribes the user quaterly(4 times/year) ,but charges them only once a year.

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

A subscriptions renews every 3rd month per year,but i want the user to be charged only once.It must be recurring.

Comment: That seems interesting. What have you tried so far ? Could you paste the code you have used, and where you are stuck ?

Comment: based on your question, I certainly believe you should buy woocommerce subscription extension or use other membership plugin and hire someone to set-up things for you

Comment: @silver i am using woocommerce subscriptions but cannot find a way to solve this.